# How to Debug Thread Pool Starvation on .NET Framework (Not .NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, async-await, threadpool

I am trying to troubleshoot a .NET 4.8 ASP.Net application.
I can see there are [tools and instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/debug-threadpool-starvation) on how to Debug Thread Pool Starvation on .NET Core - - but I don't see how to do this on a .NET Framework ASP.Net app.

Are there any tools and/or instructions for Debugging Thread Pool Starvation on .NET Framework?
Any advice on how to do this that doesn't involve upgrading to .NET Core?

I tried using the tools and instructions for .NET Core but the tools do not recognize the ASP.Net application running in IIS.

Through New Relic analysis it appears that Thread Pool Starvation is occurring.  I see API calls that normally take milliseconds to process all-of-a-sudden take seconds to process immediately after I see Available Threads go to zero or close to zero.  These long durations do not happen on any specific API endpoint, and seem randomly distributed across all API endpoints.

I've corrected several obvious misuses of `Task.Result` and `Task.Wait()` in the code and although that helped, it did not eliminate the issue.  I've also increased the Worker processes on the application pool, increasing the number of threads, this web app is running on and have seen the issue reduced, but not eliminated, while not incurring any CPU overhead.  So I must be missing something -- I just don't know what.

Comment: Why are you using .NET Framework? You're missing a lot of new features and performance improvements in .NET

Comment: The application has been developed over 20 years and analysis shows it will require weeks to months of effort to convert to .NET Core.  Plans are under way to do so - but in the meantime I need a solution.

Comment: Use [PerfView](https://github.com/microsoft/perfview) to collect an ETW trace. Then look into the events to find something interesting.

Comment: The article applies to .NET Framework as well. The tools may be different but the techniques are the same. The counters in the page you link are available through Windows Performance Monitor too. Visual Studio, WinDbg, dotnet dumps, ProcDump and other tools can force the creation of a memory dump from a process that can be loaded in Visual Studio to inspect parallel stacks and tasks.